# How to plot polar coordinates?

Tags: plotting, coordinate-transformation

I'm trying to plot polar coordinates, that is to plot surfaces of constant parameters $r$ and $\theta$. Which are related to the cartesian ones by
$$
x = r \sin \theta\\
y = r \cos \theta
$$
One way is to use countor plot as

```
Show[ContourPlot[ Evaluate@Table[x^2 + y^2 == a^2, {a, 1, 6}], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5},ContourStyle -> Directive[Dashed, Gray]],
ContourPlot[Evaluate@Table[y == Tan[a] x, {a, 0,\[Pi], 1/\[Pi]}], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, ContourStyle -> Directive[Dashed, Gray]]]
```

which results in

[image]

This is not bad but there are some problem around the $\{0,0\}$ point and I'm also struggling to nicely devide the angle by the radial lines.

Another options is

```
ParametricPlot[{r Cos[t], r Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {r, 0, 3}, Mesh -> Automatic]
```

which results in

[image]

This is a much nicer graph, but I am not able to remove the colour and I am also lacking control with the Mesh.

Is there a simpler way to do this?
Note that I am aware that we can do this manually by `Graphics` and `Line` functions, but I want to plot other, more complicated coordinates where this would no be an options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ParametricPlot[{r Cos[t], r Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {r, 0, 3}, 
 Mesh -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> None];
```

[image]

```
ParametricPlot[{r Cos[t], r Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {r, 0, 3}, Mesh -> 4, PlotStyle -> None]
```

[image]

Trying to answer your comment

```
ParametricPlot[{r Cos[t], r Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {r, 0, 3},
 Mesh -> {Subdivide[0, 2 Pi, 12], Subdivide[0, 2 Pi, 12]},
 PlotStyle -> None]
```

[image]

By changing one or both `Subdivide` - parameters, `MeshStyle` or `BoundaryStyle` you have full control:

```
ParametricPlot[{r Cos[t], r Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {r, 0, 3},
 Mesh -> {Subdivide[0, 2 Pi, 12], Subdivide[0, 2 Pi, 4]},
 BoundaryStyle -> {Red, Thickness[0.005], Dashed},
 MeshStyle -> Dashed,
 PlotStyle -> None]
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to have more control over Mesh lines? For example I would like to divide the circle equally by having a radial line at each π/6 radians. That is to have 12 radial lines but at the same time make sure that one line coincides with the y-axis.

Answer (score 5):

**Using `PolarPlot`:**

```
n = 6;
PolarPlot[{ n}, {θ, 0, 2 π}
 , PolarAxes -> {False, False}
 , PlotRange -> {{-n, n}, {-n, n}}
 , PlotStyle -> None
 , PolarGridLines -> {Range[0, 2 π, π/6], Range[1, n]}
 , GridLinesStyle -> {{Gray, Dashed}, {Gray, Dashed}}
 , PolarTicks -> {Range[0, 2 π - π/6, π/6], Range[1, n, 1]}
 , PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05]
 , Frame -> True
 , Axes -> False
 , Epilog -> {FaceForm[White], EdgeForm[Gray]
   , Disk[{0, 0}, 0.15]}
 ]
```

[image]

You can experiment with the `PolarAxes` options and adjust `PlotRangePadding` as required.

Answer (score 4):

You may prescibe Mesh for both coordinates and an adopted Array of Colors

```
   ParametricPlot[{r Cos[t], r Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {r, 0, 3},
     Mesh -> {5, 7}, 
     MeshShading -> RandomColor[ RGBColor[ _, _, 0.2], {5, 7}]]
```

[image: regular randomly painted mesh]

The mesh can be given explitely in coordinates

```
     ParametricPlot[{r Cos[t], r Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {r, 0, 3}, 
       Mesh -> {RandomReal[{0, 2 \[Pi]}, 5], RandomReal[{1, 3}, 7]}, 
       MeshShading -> RandomColor[ Hue[ _, 0.7, 0.8], {5, 7}]]
```

[image: randomly meshed]